# Blazor server Component not able to route to base URL after deploying to IIS

Tags: iis, blazor-server-side

We have deployed our Blazor server app to IIS ,when we browse, getting login page with http://someIp/WebTool URL after login the next component is redirecting to http://someIp/Dashboard but we need something like http://someIp/WebTool/Dashboard.The Webtool is missing after IP we tried changing  in _Host.cshtml but there is no use
can anyone please let us know where are we going wrong. We also tried  
and  app.UsePathBase("/Webtool"); in Startup.cs. Any suggestions will help, Thanks in advance

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UsePathBase("/UpgradeWeb");
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
               
                app.UseHsts();
            }
             
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>();
            services.Configure<ToolConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("ToolConfig"));
            services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
            services.AddSingleton<HttpClient>();
            var appSettingSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
            services.Configure<ApiKeyDetails>(Configuration.GetSection("ApiKeyDetails"));
            services.Configure<WebAppSettings>(appSettingSection);
            services.AddScoped<InvokeApiHandler>(); 
            services.AddScoped<SessionService>();
            services.AddScoped<DashboardService>();
            services.AddScoped<UpgradeRequestService>();
            services.AddScoped<Information>();
            services.AddScoped<ReportsService>();
            services.AddScoped<MasterConfigurationService>();
            services.AddScoped<UserMappingService>();
            services.AddScoped<RolesService>();
            services.AddScoped<AllReportsService>();
            services.AddScoped<JiraService>();
            services.AddScoped<NotificationService>();
            services.AddBlazoredSessionStorage();
        }
```

Comment: Can you show the services configuration in Startup.cs? I think it's some configuration in Identity.

Comment: Hi @Ricardo added startup.cs , please check

Comment: are you using Preview3? https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/9410 .To provide configuration for the Blazor app's base path of https://www.contoso.com/CoolApp/, the <base> tag's href attribute is set to the relative root path in the Pages/_Host.cshtml file (Blazor Server) or wwwroot/index.html file (Blazor WebAssembly): `<base href="/CoolApp/">` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio